# Displaying a sorted ObservableCollection in a ListView and have it update itself when underlying DBSet changes

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I have an `ObservableCollection` of `Film` called `Films` in my `FilmListViewModel` which I then display like this:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FilmListViewModel.Films }">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Genre" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Genre}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Items is a property and its getter looks like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Film> Films
{
    get { return this._DBcontext.Set<Film>().Local; }
}
```

When I remove a film from the collection Items, the list of films in the window is automatically updated and shortened. However, I want to do other operations on the list of films: sorting, filtering and searching. I therefore added another property to the `FilmListViewModel` called `OrderedFilms`, which:

```
public ObservableCollection<Film> OrderedFilms
{
    get 
    {
        orderedFilms = this._DBcontext.Set<Film>().Local.OrderBy(film => film.Name);
        return new ObservableCollection<Film> (orderedFilms);
    }
 }
```

In thew `ListView` I change `ItemsSource` to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding FilmListViewModel.OrderedFilms }"
```

However, if I then remove a film from the underlying table in the `_DBContext` the list of films in the window is not updated. I suspect the reason is that the getter of `OrderedFilms` actually constructs a new `ObservableCollection` and returns that.

How can I display the underlying table of Films in a modified fashion (filtered, sorted, etc.) and still have it updated in the window correctly when the table changes?

Comment: Create `CollectionView` on `Films`

Comment: You can post this as an answer if you want to and I will accept since this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) class is nothing more than an implementation of a list with change notifications (`INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`). The important thing though is that it has a **storage** semantics, so even the constructors that accept `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` simply create a copy (snapshot) from the passed collection.

So while your `Films` property is an accessor to the real observable storage, the observable collection returned by the `OrderedFilms` is a disconnected ordered/filtered snapshot of the storage.

What you really need is a class that provides a **view** (sorted, filtered) of the storage, keeping reference to it and reacting to the source change notifications. Luckily WPF provides such a class out of the box called [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a view for grouping, sorting, filtering, and navigating a data collection.

You can use [`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx) method to obtain a collection view implementation for your `Films` property and then filter, sort and bind to that view.

You can find more info about `CollectionView` and `CollectionViewSource` in the MSDN documentation as well as in these useful links [How to Navigate, Group, Sort and Filter Data in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html), 
[Working with CollectionView in WPF(Filter,Sort, Group, Navigate)](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html) etc.